# What versioning strategies are available to SignalR hubs with .NET clients?

Tags: .net, wcf, signalr

WCF offers rich support for versioning services, contracts, clients etc. I'm investigating SignalR as a way for my deployed .NET clients to talk to the server, but have not found any resources mentioning how to evolve hubs and clients independently. Is there a reason for this? Surely there must be some kind of recommended best-practice for handling hub evolution (adding methods, changing parameters in existing methods, removing operations, etc) when you don't necessarily have control over client versions.

Answer (score 0):

If there is versioning issue, SignalR forces clients to upgrade or downgrade their SignalR versions by exception.

> If the version of SignalR that you have on the client is different
>   from the version that you have on the server, SignalR is often able to
>   adapt to the difference. For example, a server running SignalR version
>   2 will support clients that have 1.1.x installed as well as clients
>   that have version 2 installed. If the difference between the version
>   on the server and the version on the client is too great, or if the
>   client is newer than the server, SignalR throws an
>   InvalidOperationException exception when the client tries to establish
>   a connection. The error message is "*You are using a version of the
>   client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version X.X,
>   server version X.X*".

Related [Article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#clientsetup)

After version 2.1, SignalR supports [strongly-typed hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#stronglytypedhubs). You can use this beside of dynamic hub.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about SignalR framework version, rather, I'm talking about my own versions of hubs and clients built with SignalR